# Why only does the tangential component of gravitational force on an object in elliptical orbit do work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

This is taken from my physics textbook and it asks me to decompose the gravitational force on the orbiting object in an elliptical orbit into components normal and tangential and then explain why only the tangential component does work.

Comment: Do you know what determines whether or not a force "does work"? If not, you're asking the wrong question here.

Answer (score 1):

*. . . . . decompose the gravitational force on the orbiting object in an elliptical orbit into components normal and tangential [**to the velocity of the body**] . . . . .*

Work is done when there is a displacement along the line of action of the force.

The displacement of the object is in the same direction as that of the object's velocity (tangential) and there is no displacement at right angle to the direction of the velocity (normal).
Thus, only the component of the force in the tangential direction will do work and there is no displacement in the direction of the normal component of the force, so that component does no work.